# Python's Passlib hash output

Tags: python, hash

So I'm a bit confused regarding the use of `passlib`.  I have the following code to hash X amount of passwords with N amount of algorithms.

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               
from passlib.hash import *
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from passlib.utils import Base64Engine, h64
from base64 import b64decode
from binascii import hexlify

def hash_password(passwd):
    schemes = ["pbkdf2_sha1",
               "md5_crypt",
               "sha1_crypt",
               "sha256_crypt",
               "nthash",
               "lmhash"]

    print "Hashing \"%s\"" % passwd
    print "-----------------------------------------------"

    # Create the hashing context                                                
    pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes)

    for i in range(len(schemes)):
        pw_hash = pwd_context.encrypt(passwd, schemes[i])
        print "%s - %s" % (schemes[i], pw_hash)

    print "-----------------------------------------------"

def main():

    passwords = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("passwords.txt")]

    for i in range(len(passwords)):
        hash_password(passwords[i])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following output:

```
Hashing "Hello"
-----------------------------------------------
pbkdf2_sha1 - $pbkdf2$60000$ojQGACCEcM7ZW0vpnVMqRQ$M53EY/FaE4bn.5Peaagi51cza54
    pbkdf2_sha256 - $pbkdf2-      sha256$20000$4JxzLsWYk1KKUSoFwPifsw$6LCJ.389zCs4gaQuYTMTKUis7t/4yv.c9/mH/XFKEAo
md5_crypt - $1$uDGM/Vuu$jiygPs0AgWJQjdVkc5BbE0
sha1_crypt - $sha1$64000$ge8006iW$Ccn.2CfTJFHUNHKINw5uOaMP1U3v
sha256_crypt - $5$rounds=110000$BaeA4z3k.JSjarb5$veeo24NDYkEzMqhQqqUkjEst0FTqh9fWxxGPp/pO4xA
nthash - 916a8e7b1540ec179f196f8ddb603d85
lmhash - fda95fbeca288d44aad3b435b51404ee
-----------------------------------------------
Hashing "Password"
-----------------------------------------------
pbkdf2_sha1 - $pbkdf2$60000$fO.91/o/x/g/p3Qu5XxvLQ$HPcZm9FqiN59c7VurmE3gKPUlFk
pbkdf2_sha256 - $pbkdf2-sha256$20000$mrNWKkVISSll7D3nPGds7Q$AoEg6PiE7.YFQDxtmvKVlRk/i6niC1RVflFFZiZ1g.Y
md5_crypt - $1$0qgwC1qt$bpoGT56iTN2cHHXN3v0Hk/
sha1_crypt - $sha1$64000$D3aHiFZ3$8StKt6Kt0MVl.flOvuoulBJNPVG/
sha256_crypt - $5$rounds=110000$Zxm1u65zMawD1.2F$pqywgWCi556iuBTxemWIccy68IBQxqAKZgHYc0MAFY4
nthash - a4f49c406510bdcab6824ee7c30fd852
lmhash - e52cac67419a9a224a3b108f3fa6cb6d
-----------------------------------------------
Hashing "NewPassword"
-----------------------------------------------
pbkdf2_sha1 - $pbkdf2$60000$Uao1RgjhPEcI4dzbG8OYkw$TWkaN5uJ5HMh3tV75wEnMkYjZVI
pbkdf2_sha256 - $pbkdf2-sha256$20000$55zT2tub8/6f0zqHUOrdOw$voDY5VObZQieFDCqG2of1NO0NVMc4AVsznwqv9GzAhA
md5_crypt - $1$CkQuGd5z$1CcBnpwL4cFPOYiw958pZ1
sha1_crypt - $sha1$64000$hIbbDQIi$J.1kLykb3tzFUPrHZZ23TcSj.zAR
sha256_crypt - $5$rounds=110000$g7J4/8teBFGyKmI2$OakX25d3mePIAj9V1UYDWWBayaMfngWZ6fZOdgqg9l0
nthash - 91f172926b123808d76f4d40b1db18e5
lmhash - 09eeab5aa415d6e4d408e6b105741864
```

I have two questions:

1. Repeated runs of this script give me different outputs of the hash, even though I'm not using a salt and the same algorithm is performed.
2. I have searched all over, but have not been able to find how to actually extract the legitimate hash from the result of .encrypt().  Is this even possible?  What type of conversion do I have to do on the encoding since nt/lmhash seem fine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`passlib` automatically salts the password when you call [`encrypt`](http://pythonhosted.org//passlib/password_hash_api.html?highlight=salt#passlib.ifc.PasswordHash.encrypt) for most hash types:

> **classmethod PasswordHash.encrypt(secret, **kwds)**
>
> Digest password using format-specific algorithm, returning resulting hash string.
>
> For most hashes supported by Passlib, the returned string will contain: an algorithm identifier, a cost parameter, **the salt string**, and finally the password digest itself.

That explains the output you see for most of the hashes. `nthash` and `lmhash` are both documented as not supporting salts, which explains why they have a simpler output.

For your second question, I would say that in general you *shouldn't* pull the actual hash out, because `passlib` is designed to use the entire hash string returned by `encrypt` to verify a given password. But if you want to, you can just split the returned `pw_hash` on `$`, and take the last item:

```
digest = pw_hash.split('$')[-1]
```

This works even for hashes that aren't salted like `nthash` and `lmhash`.

Comment: I was looking at the documentation too, didn't catch that line.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay... so the fact that the salt is stored in that returned string means that when I pass that string into the `verify`, I am actually passing in both the salt and the hash? The `verify` method won't need me to pass in a separate variable `salt` because it knows to just extract the salt from the string and how to combine it with the passed in password.